# Unity3d Android build error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I'm getting the following errors. Where is the problem?

Java jdk 10.0.1 .I've looked at all the similar issues, but there's no answer at all.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.1\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that unity has some issues with jdk 10, a lot of people having jdk 10 has this problem, but it can be solved via installing jdk 8.
I had tried this and also worked for me.

Comment: happy to help you, you are most welcome, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the [Gradle version from here (latest jar file version)](https://gradle.org/install/), replace the current Gradle jar file in :

> C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.X.X.jar

and then update the classpath, it should work

Comment: It did not work. I have  even updated my entire lib folder.